# Australian Bush fire donation hacking

Tags: fraud, skimming

On the recent Australian Bushfire event, people are donating to help them. But some inhumane(cybercriminals) are stealing people's money by injecting malicious script on e-commerce and donation sites. For people, it seems that they have donated the money to the right donation site but all the credit card info along with submitted information is being diverted to the domains which are being controlled by the hackers.

My question is can this be minimized by cybersecurity awareness/education? Or how as a user we can prevent ourselves by not being the victim? and how to detect these hijacked websites?

Comment: Educating who? The end user using a legitimate site? What would we need to know?

Comment: How can a user make sure that the site he is donating is safe and not infected are there any tell tale signs?

Comment: If there were signs, then it wouldn't be an effective infection.

Answer (score 1):

If a legitimate site is compromised, there is little that the end-user can do.

The best place to prevent a problem is the site itself. After the problem materializes, the charges need to be reversed by the credit card companies. Then the criminals need to be pursued by the authorities.